# wxpython tree ctrl images

Tags: python, wxpython

Ok I have an example here:

**Runable Example**

[Example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12781104/example.zip)

Extract the zip files and then run otherwise it won't work at all

However when run the images won't be added to there tree ctrl and it will simply error.

**Code (Note won't run without images, see zip file above)**

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)

        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, style = wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT)
        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("")

        gr = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Grooveshark")
        pop_r = self.tree.AppendItem(gr, "Popular")
        sr = self.tree.AppendItem(gr, "Search")

        dr = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Download")

        pr = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Pandora")
        stat_r = self.tree.AppendItem(pr, "Stations")

        image_list = wx.ImageList(16, 16)
        grooveshark = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/grooveshark (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
        popular     = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/popular (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
        search      = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/search (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
        download    = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/download (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
        pandora     = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/playlist_icon (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())
        stations    = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/stations (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap())

        self.tree.SetPyData(gr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(gr, grooveshark, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(pop_r, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(pop_r, popular, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(sr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(sr, search, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(dr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(dr, download, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(pr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(pr, pandora, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(stat_r, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(stat_r, stations, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = wx.App(False)

    f = TestFrame()
    f.Show()
    a.MainLoop()
```

Why?

I followed the demo in the wxPython demo app and no luck.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing.

Comment: It includes images so it is in a ZIP files otherwise there would be no point as without the images the code won't run

Comment: You should try and post a sample of it here however, because a lot of problems can be spotted without actually running the code.  Most people aren't going to download and unzip your code to help you find out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Ok I posted it, I figured including a sample app will help because people then have a starting point to go off of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems with you code.

1. Not all of your images are 16px x 16px, but you are trying to add them to image list that should contain only 16 x 16 images. To solve this you should scale them to 16 x 16 before adding to a list.
2. You should assign image list to tree object before applying images to tree items.

Here is fixed code:

```
import wx

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1)

        self.tree = wx.TreeCtrl(self, style = wx.TR_HIDE_ROOT)
        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot("")

        gr = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Grooveshark")
        pop_r = self.tree.AppendItem(gr, "Popular")
        sr = self.tree.AppendItem(gr, "Search")

        dr = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Download")

        pr = self.tree.AppendItem(self.root, "Pandora")
        stat_r = self.tree.AppendItem(pr, "Stations")

        image_list = wx.ImageList(16, 16)
        grooveshark = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/grooveshark (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).Scale(16,16).ConvertToBitmap())
        popular     = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/popular (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).Scale(16,16).ConvertToBitmap())
        search      = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/search (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).Scale(16,16).ConvertToBitmap())
        download    = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/download (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).Scale(16,16).ConvertToBitmap())
        pandora     = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/playlist_icon (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).Scale(16,16).ConvertToBitmap())
        stations    = image_list.Add(wx.Image("images/stations (Custom).png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).Scale(16,16).ConvertToBitmap())

        self.tree.AssignImageList(image_list)

        self.tree.SetPyData(gr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(gr, grooveshark, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(pop_r, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(pop_r, popular, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(sr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(sr, search, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(dr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(dr, download, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(pr, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(pr, pandora, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)
        self.tree.SetPyData(stat_r, None)
        self.tree.SetItemImage(stat_r, stations, wx.TreeItemIcon_Normal)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = wx.App(False)

    f = TestFrame()
    f.Show()
    a.MainLoop()
```